# IMGKit displays blank image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltoimage, imgkit

My application has an activities database, and I'm trying to use IMGKit to render the show view of an activity as an image file that can be then used on other platforms.  I feel like I've implemented IMGKit properly, but all I'm getting is a blank image.

Controller action:

```
def show
    @activity = Activity.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.jpg do
        html = render_to_string
        kit = IMGKit.new(html)
        img = kit.to_img(:jpg)
        send_data img, type: "image/jpeg", disposition: "inline"
      end
    end
end
```

Not sure if there's anything else applicable?

Edit - this is the view it should be rendering, show.jpg.erb

```
<body>
    <main style="background-color:blue;color:white;">
        <h1 style="font-size:20px;"><%= @activity.title %></h1>
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </main>
</body>
```